# Bluetooth Not working on Start or after Sleep/Hibernation

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, bluetooth

Bluetooth doesn't work and disappear from Device Manger On Normal Start(Quick Start) and after Sleep or Hibernation.
It Only works after Restarts.
Hardware is Not available or Unplugged is shown in Device Manger after turning on 'Show Hidden Devices'.
It works fine after every restarts..
Tried Clean Installation of Windows and even Swapped HDD and installed fresh windows but Problem Remains.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the Bluetooth hardware is faulty or intermittent.  I suggest getting the Manufacturer's hardware test suite and run hardware tests.

I had a Bluetooth daughter card fail on a ThinkPad X230 and I had to replace it.  All well now.

Comment: The Hardware is perfectly fine. It does work after a Restart. The Power management Option is also turned off. Still Hardware dissapears after sleep or even a Fast Startup